# How to start number entry right side of the text box?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

In ASP.NET Web Application

Usually in Text-box numbers starts from left side of the text-box

But i want the numbers to start from Right to left

I check in properties of text-box to any alignment but i didn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it with css styling, add "text-align:right" to the control.

Example:

```
<asp:TextBox id="textBoxNumber" runat="server" style="text-align:right"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use CSS property "direction".

Example:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="rtol"></asp:TextBox>
```

CSS:

```
.rtol { direction:rtl; }
```